# Android: send data from adapter class to Activity

Tags: java, android

I want to add pictures to my favorite activity when a user tap on a picture. So far I'm able to get the data and display it but for some reason whenever I tap on an image it displays the favorited image, however, when I recheck the favorite activity by clicking on it, it shows empty.
Here's the little flow chart.

`imageOnTap` is implemented on `RecyclerAdapter` class. I have my `Favorite activity` and `MainActivity`.Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Here's my `MyRecyclerAdapter` class

```
     @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

          holder.nameTxt.setText(albums.get(position).getName());
          holder.img.setImageResource(albums.get(position).getImage());

         //listener
            holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
                    Toast.makeText(c,albums.get(pos).getName() + " ,added to favorite ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt("favorite",albums.get(pos).getImage());
            editor.commit();

            Toast.makeText(c,albums.get(pos).getName() + " ,added to favorite ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(c, favorite.class);
           // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, albums.get(pos).getImage());
            c.startActivity(intent);




                }
            });
        }
```

Here's my favorite activity

```
  public class favorite extends AppCompatActivity {
        int favImage;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorite);

                ImageView displayImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.movieImage);




         SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);

            displayImage.setImageResource(settings.getInt("Favorite", 0));


    //            Intent intent = getIntent();
    //            if (intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
    //                favImage = intent.getIntExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,image);
    //                displayImage.setImageResource(favImage);
    //
    //            }
             }
        }
```

Here's my MainActivity

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.nav_favorite) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,favorite.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
```

Comment: if (id == R.id.nav_favorite) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,favorite.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }  you are missing intent value onNavigationItemSelected

Comment: replace `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` with your own constant key like `MY_IMAGE_URL`.

Comment: @AmrutBidri do you mean I should change like this ->.    intent.putExtra("MyImage",albums.get(pos).getImage());

Comment: @quicklearner Yeah I guessed that. What should I put there?

Comment: yes. change the key

Comment: @AmrutBidri I tried that but no luck. I think there is something wrong with onNavigationItemSelected .

Comment: you are not passing any extra value in that method. that can be the case

Answer (score 1):

If you are checking favourite activity from nav menu then it will not display anything afterall you are not passing any intent extras in it. Is it being display when you click the image? Are you getting intent params null here?

Comment: when I tap on on the image it displays the image in favorite activity

Comment: you must save this intent value in shared pref or assign it to a static constant if you want to use it in future. Pass this value in intent of favourite activity, when opening from menu.

Comment: so should I save the intent value in my RecyclerAdapter class by using sharedPref and pass that value to favorite activity?

Comment: yes, or save it to a static variable and pass it  in nav item click intent

Comment: I have edited my code using sharedPref. Can you please take a look at it? I don't see anything when i tap on it

Comment: More better way is to make a static array containing Drawable ids of various drawables that u are using in your adapter. Now you should save the item position in onclick method to shared pref. Now in favourite activity get this position from shared pref, get the drawable from the list with this position as index and then set the image

Comment: the best way is to make your adapter list as static. Now save the position in shared pref on onclick, and retrieve the position in fav activity and subsequently get the the image by getting item from list with the position as index  `editor.putInt("favorite",position);`   `displayImage.setImageResource(albums.get(settings.getInt("Favorite", 0).getimage());`

Answer (score 1):

Use those preferences:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx.getApplicationContext());
```

In your case it might be different activities observe different areas of settings.

THAT IS:

use:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx.getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt("favorite",albums.get(pos).getImage());
            editor.commit();
```

instead of:

```
SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt("favorite",albums.get(pos).getImage());
            editor.commit();
```

AND
this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx.getApplicationContext());

            displayImage.setImageResource(settings.getInt("Favorite", 0));
```

instead of:

```
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);

            displayImage.setImageResource(settings.getInt("Favorite", 0));
```

Comment: I'm sorry but where do I put that?

Comment: @user7062312 updated. Everywhere set detting var to this value

Comment: Sorry i'm not getting what you trying to say

Comment: Just to confirm, are you using context when you posted ctx.getApplicationContext() ?

Comment: I tried your code and it displays nothing. Looks like no data has been passed